# When the iframe is focused, the parent window events are not called. How to prevent it?

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I have some `window` `'keydown'` event listeners in the main DOM added.
I have also an youtube api `iframe` in the DOM. When I click on any element in the DOM, all `keydown` listeners are called, but when I click in the youtube iframe (eg. to volume up), all `keydown` listeners stop working.

I know that `iframe` has its own `document` and `window` objects and perhaps the browser switches the window and listen the iframe listeners, but is there any way to keep the parent window keyboard listeners working event when the iframe is focused?

Comment: No, there isn't. That would be a huge security problem.

Comment: There is no way to listen to these events "when the iframe is focused", but do you really need this iframe to be focused? Otherwise, [here is one hack-around](https://jsfiddle.net/yz0m7b4e/), but note that this will obviously break YT's own key listeners and thus their keyboard controls.

Comment: @Kaiido this is what I was looking for. Thank you, if you want, answer my question with this comment and I will upvote it and mark as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to listen to these events *"when the iframe is focused"*.

However, if you don't really need this iframe has the focus, then you can try to force it not gain the focus.

To do so is a bit hackish, different browsers seems to have different behaviors, but the gist is quite simple:
Listen for your main Window's `blur` event, and from there, call its `focus()` method.

As said previously, that's mainly an hack, and requires tweaks for different browsers; Firefox needs it to be called right away, Chrome needs a little timeout (luckily both are not conflicting though).

Also note that this will obviously break YoubeTube's own key listeners and thus their keyboard controls.

**Use at your own risk, and be sure to test in various environments**:

```js
document.onkeydown = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.key);
}

onblur = e => {
  if (e.currentTarget === e.target) {
    focus(); // FF
    setTimeout(focus, 20); // Chrome
  }
};
overlay.onclick = function() {
  this.remove()
};
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"><button>begin demo</button></div>
<iframe srcdoc="<input value='can not type here'><button onclick='alert(`clicked`)'>button still works</button>"></iframe>
```

[And as a jsfiddle which allows iframes to YouTube.](https://jsfiddle.net/yz0m7b4e/)